# Define Projection - Error 000732 - Dataset Does Not Exist or Is Not Supported

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arccatalog, error-000732

I am working with a shapefile that currently does not have any projections associated with it. However, when I attempt to Define the Projection, I am met with Error 000732. I have tried doing this in both ArcMap as well as ArcCatalog with no luck in either. The dataset does exist, the address is written properly, but I have had no success.

Comment: I think I've seen a different error if you don't have write permissions, but can you check that anyway? Write permission to the folder.

Comment: Also a technical article: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010149

Comment: Perhaps review our [self-assembling FAQ on ERROR 000732](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000732?sort=frequent)

Comment: What does that shapefile look like in Windows Explorer?  i.e. which of its expected files are present?

Comment: @mkennedy I have full read and write permissions

Comment: @PolyGeo It looks like a standard list for the shapefile (.cpg, .dbf, .sbn, .sbx, .shp, .shx)

Comment: What are the precise parameter values that you are providing to the tool?  What is the full error message message that you are receiving?